# Set IP from header before php code is running

Tags: php, openx

Since i dont want to change openx coding and i wanna to set the IP from header to the php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Is there any way to extract a IP from header (pre-set by other program already in load balancing web server) before any php code running?

Comment: so you want to get the value of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`...?

Comment: yes i want to get value from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in php, but want to set the ip in linux before php setup the server var

Comment: you want to be able to... set the... what? can you be a bit clearer?

Comment: for some reason, i need to extract a IP from header, and since i dont want to update the php code, and want it as same as original. Thus, i need to set this $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] before php use it

Comment: that variable is automatically sent in a header, and it is received in `$_SERVER` automatically... what are you asking?

Comment: i want to ask how can i config the $_SERVER var in linux or any way to config it before php use it

Comment: you want to modify the variable? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] before PHP wrapper does (cgi/module). But using 
the .htaccess php_value "auto_prepend_file", you can request a script to be executed before anything else, and this way, you're free to set $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] with anything you want in it.

Comment: auto_prepend_file is something like include right? can it have a  condition filter, like i want a file, b file to use the prepend but c file not

Comment: Not easily, but this is easy to deal with in the script - <? if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "filec") return; then do things you want

Comment: THX, this answer is better than some useless comment above